# Constant movement in snake game

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a [snake game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_%28video_game%29), but I am stuck. I want the snake to move in constant movement.

However, the snake moves only when I pressing the arrow. If I release the arrow the snake stops moving.

Here is my current code:

```
import sys, pygame
window_size = ( 400, 400 )

white = ( 255, 255, 255 )

class Player():
  image = pygame.image.load( 'snikebodydraw.png')
  rect = image.get_rect()

player = Player()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( window_size )

done = False

while not done:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      sys.exit()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:


      if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        move = (-10, 0 )
        player.rect = player.rect.move(move)
      if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        move = ( 10, 0 )
        player.rect = player.rect.move(move)
      if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        move = ( 0,-10 )
        player.rect = player.rect.move(move)
      if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        move = ( 0, 10 )
        player.rect = player.rect.move(move)

  screen.fill( white )
  screen.blit( player.image, player.rect )

  pygame.display.flip()
```

how can i change this code to make the snake keep moving even without pressing the arrow key?

Comment: Look at the `if` statements in the `while` loop. The only time `move = (X, Y )` is called is when you're pressing a button. You need that to happen even when you don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of only moving when a key is pressed, the movement should happen on all iterations of the `while` loop and pressing a key should only change the *direction* of the movement.

```
import sys, pygame
window_size = ( 400, 400 )

white = ( 255, 255, 255 )

class Player():
  image = pygame.image.load( 'snikebodydraw.png')
  rect = image.get_rect()

player = Player()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( window_size )

move = ( 0, 0 ) # init movement

done = False

while not done:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      sys.exit()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    
    
      if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        move = ( -10, 0 )
      if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        move = ( 10, 0 )
      if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        move = ( 0, -10 )
      if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        move = ( 0, 10 )

  player.rect = player.rect.move( move )

  screen.fill( white )
  screen.blit( player.image, player.rect )

  pygame.display.flip()
```